# Checking if a file is still open

Tags: perl, file, operators

I use `ffmpeg` to reduce size and convert a video file with a batch. Meanwhile, I'd like to check if the converting process of this video is done, using a Perl script.

Is the `-t` operator checking that ?
Or a simple executable check `-x` does the trick ? Or something else ?
Thank you !

Comment: Neither `-t` nor `-x` will help with what you're trying to do.  Is it possible to track the `ffmpeg` process? Presumably when that process exits the conversion is complete.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot install the `FFmpeg` perl module on this server... So the only way is to batch the converting process of the video which is becoming independant without any returns... I can't believe that Perl is unable to know if a file is still in writing mode!

Comment: @Satch, Re "*I can't believe that Perl is unable to know if a file is still in writing mode!*", Perl can tell. The answer is unconditionally "no", because there is no such thing as "a file in write mode".

Comment: @Satch, "*Unfortunately, I cannot install the FFmpeg perl module on this server*", You completely misunderstood Grant. He was suggesting you should check for the existence of the `ffmpeg` process that was launched to compress the video.

Comment: ...Otherwise, you'll need some system-dependent way of enumerating file handles. `lsof` could be used on linux.

Comment: Ok ok, I'll check the process. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's inadvisable to argue with people whose help you're getting for free

It's quite possible to examine what file handles are open and by what processes, but the method varies according to the operating system. And it sounds like you're running `ffmpeg` on a remote system so it's even less straightforward

The usual method would be cooperative locking, but `ffmpeg` doesn't do that

If you're running a batch job, then the obvious way is for the job to create a flag file once the `ffmpeg` run is complete. Then you need only to wait for the existence of that file to be sure that `ffmpeg` has finished

Please don't be overconfident in future, or you will get only the answers that you deserve